# Custom UITextField

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitextfield, rgb

I know that it has been asked before but I hadn't seen any answers that I could use. So I am sorry for asking a repeat Q but it is kind of important. So is there any way to change the background color of a rounded UITextField. I have RGB values that I want to use but I can only change the corners using the background property.

Comment: If you're a paid developer, you might want to try and see if the iOS 5 beta does what you're expecting.

Comment: If I make another app it will be iOS 5. I am the son of a paid developer but it is for a business. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1971598/iphone-uitextfield-controlling-background-color/4221061#4221061) covers what you need. In short, rounded UITextFields are drawn with a bunch of other UIImageViews behind the scenes, so you need to change the button style to something else and then make the modifications you need.

Comment: Thank you, I hadn't seen that answer before but it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You could set the background of `UITextField` using [`background`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITextField/background) property , I could not find setting color as background in the documentation for `UITextField` So you could consider using an image, which is formed from your RGB values,and set the as background of your text field.

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIImage *background
```

Like below.

```
myTextfield.background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"];
```

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the answer.