# background color not working as expected

Tags: iphone

I'm trying to apply a custom RGB color to background, but it is not displaying the intended color, instead it always shows white:

```
UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithRed:76 green:76 blue:76 alpha:1.0];
mainTable.backgroundColor       = color;
self.scrollView.backgroundColor = color;
```

however if I change one param to max eg Red:255 then I do see red color, any idea why I'm not seeing the color I'm looking for: 76 76 76 should have given some kind of dark grey color.

Thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The arguments for [`colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html) need to be `CGFloat`s on a scale from 0 to 1, where 0 is 0 and 1 is 255. Therefore, your code should look more like this:

```
UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithRed:76.0/255.0
                                 green:76.0/255.0
                                  blue:76.0/255.0
                                 alpha:1.0];
```

Comment: what was i doing :). I read that in document but for some reason I was using 0-1 only for alpha. Thank you very much that saved me from wasting lots of hrs :)

Comment: And do not forget the .0 (or f suffix). Otherwise your operation will be computed with integers. And there the possible results are 0 and 1 only. That drove me crazy the other day :)

Answer (score 2):

This alway got me. many of my Graphic Apps show me the Color in HEX anyway. We've switched all of our code to use a macro to convert the HEX values to the 0-1 scaled values.

```
// Color RGB ease of access
#define UIColorFromRGB(rgbValue) [UIColor \
    colorWithRed:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255.0 \
    green:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8))/255.0 \
    blue:((float)(rgbValue & 0xFF))/255.0 alpha:1.0]
```

So after adding the Above to your .pch you can then use:

```
UIColor color = UIColorFromRGB(0x4C4C4C);
mainTable.backgroundColor       = color;
self.scrollView.backgroundColor = color;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to work with `CGFloat` between 0 and 1 and not `int` for your 
`UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithRed:76 green:76 blue:76 alpha:1.0];`

From [iOS API](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html) :

> colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha:
>
> Creates and returns a color object using the specified opacity and RGB
>   component values.
>   + (UIColor *)colorWithRed:(CGFloat)red green:(CGFloat)green blue:(CGFloat)blue alpha:(CGFloat)alpha Parameters
>
> ```
> The red component of the color object, specified as a value from 0.0 to 1.0. green
>
> The green component of the color object, specified as a value from 0.0 to 1.0. blue
>
> The blue component of the color object, specified as a value from 0.0 to 1.0. alpha
>
> The opacity value of the color object, specified as a value from 0.0 to 1.0.
> ```