# iOS UITextField with gradien background

Tags: ios, xcode, uitextfield, subclass

I'd like to have a UITextField with a gradient background to make one of the options of my project a bit more visually appealing.

I'm trying to subclass UITextField class overriding initWithFrame, but it doesn't work. I've never tried to subclass a UIControl before so I guess I'm missing something.

Could somebody give me a hand? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this answer: [iPhone UITextField background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1971598/iphone-uitextfield-controlling-background-color)

And add a gradient with CAGradientLayer

Comment: It seems to be that it was easier than I thought. I was doing all rigth but the problem is pointed out in the link you attached. When subclassing UITextField, the textField must not be that with rounded corners. So finally I subclassed UITextField, added the gradient on initWithFrame and set the type as borderless. Everything works pretty well. The thing also is I was looking for a programatically solutions, without having to use a image (jpg, png or other) for the gradient. This way resizing is not an issue. Thanks a lot to you all.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
textView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"gradient.jpg"]];
```

But you will have to change the control to the TextView.

Answer (score 0):

The `UITextField` has property `background`, which is of type `UIImage`. So you can either draw an `UIImage` at runtime or load a ready image and set it as background of your UITextField. This way you can achieve whatever look you like for your text field.

Answer (score 0):

you are just near to it subclassing is best idea for it but instead of overriding `initWithFrame` just use as below code in your subclassed .m file

```
 - (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds
{
    return CGRectInset(bounds, 5, 0);
}

- (CGRect)editingRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds
{
    return CGRectInset(bounds, 5, 0);   
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    UIImage *textFieldBackground = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"text_field_teal.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(15.0, 5.0, 15.0, 5.0)];
    [textFieldBackground drawInRect:[self bounds]];
}
```

as  this works for me i think it will works for you
Happy Coding :)
Enjoy the Day !!